# How to input a player name?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am attempting to create an RPG, in the game the player can name their character. I ran into some trouble where it says that the name is undefined. I understand raw_input in python 2, and that is not the issue, I have tested that, if I change 'input' to 'raw_input' it does not work at all, it will just end the program. And I want to know if there is any one who can help me sort out this issue.

The following is my code (I have taken my name out of the credits for privacy purposes):

```
import random

PN = 0
Hit = 0
health = 50
level = 0
EXP = 0
nameless_variable_1 = 0

print("Hello, and welcome to my creation!")
print("To begin type 1")
print("to see credits type 2")
print("to quit go to the X button in the corner and click it")
print("to continue type what you want to do and hit enter on your keyboard.")
nameless_variable_1 = input("what is your choice??????")

if nameless_variable_1 == 2:
    print("................. The entire game")
    print("do you want to play the game now?")
    print("if you do press one and then hit enter")
    nameless_variable_1 = input(" ")

if nameless_variable_1 == 1:
    PN = input("what is your character Name?")
    print("it is the year 2019 and you are trying to assasinate an important person")
    print("if you fail at this task, you can and probably will die.")
```

Comment: Is there any question ??

Comment: I am asking for help with my issue.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3?

Comment: Bear in mind that `input` will return a `str`, not an `int`, so you need to compare to e.g. `'1'`, not `1`.

Comment: so I need to make it '1' not just 1 in the if nameless_variable_1 == 1 bit?

Comment: That depends on if you are using python 2 or python 3!

Comment: See [_How do I ask a good question?_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help center.

Comment: I am using python 2

Comment: why did my question get down voted 7 times?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but I think I know why others did. First, you did not actually ask a question here, nor did you clearly state the problem. Second, you claim to have understood `raw_input` while you really did not, as the whole issue is exactly because of you not understanding it. Third, you did not provide a [MCVE], so finding out what exactly your problem is, takes a lot of time, which people find annoying. I'd suggest before asking your next question, make sure to have read [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ans stick to the proposed structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 2, `raw_input` will return a string while `input` will return an evaluated string. Therefore `input` works fine for the numbers, since `eval('2')` gives `2` (as an integer). However it does not work for the name, and hence `eval("John")` throws an error.

I would recomment to use `raw_input` throughout your code. 
For the numbers you may then compare to a string
`if nameless_variable_1 == "2":`
and for the name it will not throw an error.

Comment: Thanks! That worked better than what I was attempting to do!